# Excel Worksheet Change event not firing unless cell is manually changed for the Private Sub Worksheet_Change_D

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-excel-2016

All the code works except the Private Sub Worksheet_Change_D(ByVal target As Range). The column I8:I200 has formula that shows updated change from another sheet. If I8:I200 shows as completed, then the column F should update with those criteria. It works manually if I click into the cell I8 and F8 will change but it should do that automatically. I have another VBA worksheet change that affects the column F but that is a manual change so that is good. Is that going to be a problem for this code? How should I go about this? This is under the actual worksheet not ThisWorkbook.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change_D(ByVal target As Range)
Dim WorkRng As Range
Dim rng As Range
Dim xOffsetColumn As Integer

Set WorkRng = Intersect(Application.ActiveSheet.Range("I8:I200"), target)
xOffsetColumn = -3

If Not WorkRng Is Nothing Then
Application.EnableEvents = False 'disable events
For Each rng In WorkRng
    If rng.Value = "" Then
        rng.Offset(0, xOffsetColumn).Value = "Not Started"
    Else
        If rng.Value = "Completed" Then
            rng.Offset(0, xOffsetColumn).Value = "Completed"
        Else
            If rng.Value = "Pending" Then
                rng.Offset(0, xOffsetColumn).Value = "Pending Prior Task"
            Else
                rng.Offset(0, xOffsetColumn).Value = "Not Started"
            End If
        End If
    End If
Next
Application.EnableEvents = True 'enable events
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Please don’t post 150 lines of code that works;  create an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve "How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example") that shows the problem.

Comment: This is my first time posting. I will adjust it. Thanks!